# Product data(image,text) from a Flash website into a file (excel, access, flat, csv, xml...etc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a flash page(URL) that has a product image and some text like color,category,price etc.I would like to know how to save/download data (image & all the data associated with product) from a Flash website into a file (may be excel, access, flat, csv, xml...etc).

Answer (score 0):

For things like that, you`ll need a component that can read/parse/play flash objects, such component that has the ability to extract the text and images from the flash object.

Flash-based websites transfer flash objects over HTTP, usually, binary objects, that can't be trivially interpreted as plain text, hence extracting text/images from it is not a simple task.